# Poor Performance on rs.next() on query result in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, performance

I am attempting to export the results of a query into a CSV, however this problem persists even when I am not trying to export to CSV. The following code has the same logic and steps as my actual code but this has changed headers and variable names to make it clearer.
Here is the code:

```java
            rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

            //CSV HEADER
            outputLines.add("Cow"+d+"Horse"+d+"Sheep"+newLineDelimiter);
            int number =0;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                //This was added to see the output speed in catalina.out
                System.out.println(number);
                number++;
                Farm.LoadXmlByEntry(passStatement, rs.getFarm("entry_c"), tag);

                //Declares variables as well as puts them into correct type, then escapes them as to not break the CSV format, this is a string
                String cow = String.format("%s", Farm.CowNumber());
                String horse = String.format("%s", ticket.HorseNumber());
                String sheep = String.format("%s", ticket.SheepNumber());

                //this is just a simple escaping sequence so any entered characters do not break the CSV format
                cow   = Escape.CSV(cow);
                horse = Escape.CSV(horse);
                sheep = Escape.CSV(sheep);

                outputLines.add(cow+d+horse+d+sheep+newLineDelimiter);
            }
```

Now, I added `number` as an out put so I could see the rough speed at which `rs.next()` is running. The result is extremely slow when the actual response from the query is very quick.
Here is the real-time recording of the numbers counting(It does slow down a tad as the numbers climb, the amount of lines periodically 5000+):

[image: Counting Speed]

The `rs.next()` seems to be causing performance issues. **Is there a better way to approach this that is more efficient?**

Not the exact query but changed to match the above syntax, "SELECT cow, horse, sheep FROM Farm_Table;" It also has date ranges for the WHERE statement, but I am  not using them as I am just selecting all.

I am using Java 6, I believe the JDBC version is spring-jdbc-3.0.6, and I have not set the Fetch Size.

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: also add some info about what jdbc driver (version) you are using and what the fetch size is. (add these infos to your question, dont post it in the comments)

Comment: Added it to the bottom of current question.

Comment: Attach a profiler like https://www.yourkit.com/ and you will spot the problem immediately.

Comment: I was asking about the version of your jdbc driver (not the java version). Also how long does it take if you measure the time (without doing the system.out). For the FetchSize see (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int))

Comment: @second It takes just as long without the print.out, I thought that it might slow it down but it still takes a long time. I am having trouble finding the quickest way to find my JDBC driver version, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I guess you use a jar that you included into your build path. Just open it and check the manifest. Normally theres the info. If you use maven or gradle just check their respective configuration.

Comment: @second So after checking the only thin g the manifest says is version 1.0

Comment: Look for Implementation-Version not manifest version

Comment: I grepped the entire directory and outside of it for that and no hits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196220/discussion-between-second-and-seth-r).